# Can not use the BLL I created

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 projects in this app. One of this is supposed to make the connection with the database.

[image]

I am trying to add the methods from the BLL project to the MVC_BO. I already added the reference, but when I try the "using BLL" the MVC_BO does not recognize the reference.

Both files in BLL project are using namespace BLL (as you can see in the image below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnyge.png)

Comment: BLL versus BL ?? Are both projects using same framework version?

Comment: The BL is because I wanted to show that is not being recognized. Even if I write BLL it will not find it. Both are using framework 4.8

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019

Comment: Is the actual namespace called `BLL` ?

Comment: @user1781290, yes "namespace BLL {..."

Comment: Your BLL project has two files.  What namespace(s) do those files contain?  When you add `using X;` to the top of your file, `X` is not the name of an assembly, it's the name of a namespace, which *usually* matches the name of the assembly, but isn't required to.  An assembly can export types in one or more namespaces.

Comment: @Amy, thank's. I really didn't know that. I thought I would refer to the name of the assembly. But both namespaces are "namespace BLL". I've just uploaded a pic with them

Comment: Your classes are not public.  In the future, please do not upload images of code.  Upload the code *as text*.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/47589

Comment: Sorry, I read this, but here my point was to show that the reference was imported, not the code itself. Bu I will be carefull thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes are not public, so nothing is being exported from that namespace.  Make your classes public.  They are internal by default.